# Android/PHP: how to POST/GET JSON data from Android to php

Tags: php, android, json

Android/PHP: how to POST/GET JSON data from Android to php?

Currently I am stuck at a point where I am sending JSONObject data to php but 
getting NULL values always in response.

## What I want:

I am sending 'username' and 'password' from Android in the form of JSONObject and want to retrieve same data in JSONObject in PHP response.

Here is my code snippet

Android_file.java

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost(register_user);
        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        try {

            jsonObject.put("username",username.getText().toString());
            jsonObject.put("password",password.getText().toString());
            StringEntity se=new StringEntity("json="+jsonObject.toString());
            //httpPost.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json"));
            httpPost.setEntity(se);
           String req=se.toString();

            HttpResponse response=httpClient.execute(httpPost);


            if(response!=null){
                InputStream is=response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
                String line=null;
                while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                    sb.append(line+"\n");
                }
                this.message=sb.toString();
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Login_check.php

```
<?php
include('../core/init.php');

 // $contents = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
  // $contents = utf8_encode($contents); 
  if($_POST['json'])
  {
  $data=json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['json']));
  $username=$data['username'];
  $password=$data['password'];
$response=array('username'=>$username,'password'=>$password);
echo json_encode($response);

  }
   else{
   $no_data=array('none'=>'no data received');
echo json_encode($no_data);
   }

    ?>
```

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong or missing some point? thanks in advance!

Comment: Please search StackOverflow before posting, it seems like this question is asked almost daily...

Comment: @Ed George- I've seen lot of answers but none of them have clear-satisfied answer what i wanted .

Comment: *Please let me know i am doing something wrong or missing some point?* ... You missed to use internet searching engine ... prolly yet another NOMTException ...

Comment: @Selvin: I've spent almost a day to get answer for this question on INTERNET on google/stackoverflow. No offence but if any of you can help/assist me then it'd be great help from you guys. I am a beginner to this concept.

Comment: off-topic: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.* in other words http://bit.ly/Vn6wfB

Comment: `setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json"));`. Remove that. You are just sending one POST parameter 'json'.

Comment: What do you mean with `getting null values in response`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what exactly is wrong with your code but I compared your code to mine which is working fine on diffrent apps and I made some changes to your code and hope that it works:

replace the part:

```
        jsonObject.put("username",username.getText().toString());
        jsonObject.put("password",password.getText().toString());
        StringEntity se=new StringEntity("json="+jsonObject.toString());
        se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json"));
        httpPost.setEntity(se);
```

With:

```
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username.getText().toString())); 
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password.getText().toString())); 
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
```

and this will be your web service (I think the problem is here):

```
<?php
include('../core/init.php');

 // $contents = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
  // $contents = utf8_encode($contents); 
  if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
  {
      $username=$_POST['username'];
      $password=$_POST['password'];
      $response = array(); 
      $response['username'] = $username; 
      $response['password'] = $password;
      echo json_encode($response);
  }
  else{
       $no_data=array();
       $no_data['none']= 'no data received';
       echo json_encode($no_data);
  }
 ?>
```

Please let me know if it fixes your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Karim. That's exactly what i was looking for and I really appreciate your help in code suggestion and pointing out mistakes. Thank you very much.

Comment: I would suggest though that you look into your code as this method is deprecated. Look into url.openConnection for future methods and use json.